# How could I send continue response from server to client by grpc in Java, like broadcase?

Tags: java, stream, grpc

How could I send continue response from server to client by grpc in Java, like broadcase? As I completed a simple call by learning the help of gRCP, but I have problem with the scenario is that one client send request to server and then server send continue response to client every 15 second.

I investigated for this, but cannot include a solution. Could you please share some suggeston on it?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC only supports unicast, not broadcast. For server to send multiple responses to client you want a server-streaming RPC.

The [Route Guide example](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java/) demonstrates server-streaming with the ListFeatures RPC (notice the `stream` keyword):

```
rpc ListFeatures(Rectangle) returns (stream Feature);
```

Then you simply call `onNext()` multiple times, one for each time you want to send to the client:

```java
if (lon >= left && lon <= right && lat >= bottom && lat <= top) {
  responseObserver.onNext(feature);
  // You could sleep here if you wanted
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. Response could be sent to client now  but error occurred. I feel that timeout error which client close the connection. Because I use "blockingStub". Error info:"io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated"

Comment: I update the value of awaitTermination and it means server could send response for  one day. Oh my god! Is there better solution for my requirement?     "channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);"

Comment: @Parke, it is unclear what error you are getting; the notifyTerminated just says "grpc closed the connection." The error is separate. I don't understand the problem you are describing. Please create a new question.